# How to avoid many null checks for a hierarchy of associated/composed/aggregated objects before a foreach loop?

Tags: c#

What is the best way to check for nulls in this situation?

```
foreach(var item in Vehicles.Car.CarModel)
{
   ...
   ...
}
```

Now the Car or CarModel can be Null and should be checked somehow. What is the best way?

Comment: How do you define "best?"

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: What is your criteria for determining which way is "best?"  Shortest possible code?  Highest performing?  Most likely to win a beauty contest?

Comment: Also, what type is `CarModel`?  It would have to implement `IEnumerable<T>` for this code to work.

Comment: I have EF and Vehicles Car and CarModel are my Table Objects. The FK can be null in database which makes the sub objects null

Comment: So it would be `foreach(item in Vehicles) { if item.car != null { } }`, etc.

Comment: Yes which means write a for then two ifs

Comment: Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this to avoid some null checks in two lines before the loop:

```
TypeOfCarModel items = Vehicles?.Car?.CarModel ?? null;

if ( items != null )
  foreach ( var item in items )
  {
  }
```

This use [Null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) and [Null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operators.

In case of a list, for example, or any other thing like that, a variant may be:

```
List<CarModelItem> items = Vehicles?.Car?.CarModel ?? new List<CarModelItem>();

foreach ( var item in items )
{
}
```

It avoids the null check because the "`IEnumerable`" is empty, but it creates an instance...

Comment: That's not the list object.  See comments above.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't understand.

Comment: {shrug} nevermind.  The OP told me something else, but accepted your answer anyway.